# Trust Anchors zone in Windows 2003 DNS

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

OK, I could be wrong...but I don't ever remember seeing this on my DC's before.  Simple 2003 domain with 8 DC's around the U.S.

I had to get into DNS to add a host record and saw this forward lookup zone.

Has it always been there and I've been blind?  How does it get there?  Am I drunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649280%28WS.10%29.aspx

What's funny is that my server is a W2k3 server...so not sure why it is even showing a trust anchor...but oh well.